# Unable to locate Element on the Android App

Tags: mobile, appium, appium-android

I am automating an android app and using AppiumDriver.
I fetched the element locator(Id) using Appium inspector. The locator is very straightforward.

I am getting below error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkYkp.jpg)

Below is my code:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id(locator_id))));
WebElement field1=(MobileElement)driver.findElement(By.id(locator_id));
field1.click();
field1.sendKeys(fieldValue);

Since I am using LamdaTest I couldn't use Appium-java version 8.
Also the page I am trying to locate element is appearing on the in-app web browser.